# AWS Lambdaをnode.jsで利用していて、callback()以降の処理を実行しないようにreturnする必要がありますか？

Tags: aws-lambda

Lambdaでcallback()のすぐ後にreturnを書いた方が良いかで悩んでいます。

以下のようなスクリプトで、`callback`以降の `console.log()`が実行されることを確認しました。

```
'use strict';

module.exports.helloWorld = (event, context, callback) => {
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    message: 'message ',
    input: event,
    }),
};

callback(null, response);
console.log('', 'log2 after callback!')
};
```

ということは、if文を使った早期returnのような感覚で`callback`を使ってしまうと、予期しない挙動が発生するということでしょうか？（普通に考えればそうなりそうです）
それを防ぐためには`callback`のすぐ後で`return`すればいいのはわかるんですが、そういうコードを個人的に見かけたことがないので自信が持てません。そうするべきでしょうか？

Comment: 予期せぬ挙動として考えている例があれば是非記載してください。callbackの時点では終了するわけではないことを活用した非同期処理も可能ですし、JSを理解してたら分かるでしょうが別関数が非同期で動いていても終わりません。if分の中では当然そこでレスポンスが戻るだけでそれ以下のコードは続行されます。https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/learn-about-difference-between-context-succeed-and-callback/

Comment: ……これが回答でよかったかもしれませんね

Answer (score 1):

callbackはあくまでも戻り値を設定するだけの関数なので、処理が終了するわけではありません。
ですので、それ以降の処理を行いたくないならreturnすべきですし、そもそもcallback以降にコードを書く必要性がそもそもないかと思います。